# Expanding dynamic div's using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

How to go about expanding each div that is initially collapsed and expands on clicking,
like the one in the given link
[Expanding div](https://angel.co/jobs?slug=angellist)

I have tried it with selenium ,by getting the div class using xpath and then have it click on it, but the problem is sometimes the div is found out twice and clicked again,
so it collapses again ,and effects it again,
I have also tried sleep ,but it didn't work

Also after clicking the div class changes to:

> djl87 job_listings fbw9 browse_startups_table_row _a _jm expanded

```
while True:
    temp=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class=' djl87 job_listings fbw9 browse_startups_table_row _a _jm']")
    action.move_to_element(temp)
    time.sleep(4)
    action.click() 
    action.perform()
    if(some_cond):
        break
```

Comment: If the div tag is dynamic try to use with xpath following/following-sibling based on your web page html structure

Comment: Ticket title doesn't really reflect described problem. Update it properly. Also note that to expand each `div` you need to repeatedly scroll page down to trigger XHR and load new divs... Do you have a code for the same?

Comment: @Andersson In this case as soon as the last div in window is expanding more divs automatically appear ,hence I don't  have to automate scrolling down to the bottom of the page.

Comment: probably that's why your script doesn't work. You need to get list of all divs first and then tap on each div

Comment: It was happening because of the offset,I set some offset while clicking on the div and it worked